# How to Secure retina images

Tags: html, image, retina

I was sondering how i can secure retina images on a server? It's for a photograph who doesn't want that every visiter is able to get the and copy @2x images from the server.

Thankx

Casper

Comment: You don't. If it's on the web and client side, and the user can see it, they can rip it. ;)

Comment: Rule #1: if you don't want it stolen - don't put it online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any web server technology (like PHP), you can put this image behind a login page or authorization script, but in the end, if the user will be able to see it, then he will be able to copy it.

Comment: Can you link me to a website or script that I may can use? @Rafael

Comment: You can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533806/hide-download-url/17533983#17533983, it's about hiding an URL, but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a user visiting your site will have to download the image in order to view it, which makes it virtually impossible to prevent them from accessing the images if they are tech savy.

However, you can prevent some of your novice users by overlaying your images with a transparent absolute positioned div. That way they'll end up right clicking the div instead of the actual image and won't get the option to save the image.

Additionally you can prevent any sort of clicks on image tags with JavaScript.

```
<img src="" onmousedown="return false;" onmousemove="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

You may want to use both approaches in case they disable JavaScript which would in turn disable the second approach and the first approach would serve as a fallback.

I would personally suggest you watermark the images.